# npm ERR! addPlacedTarball Could not remove

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I think this is the error that is halting my progress as I try to install express and dependencies. This log is too confusing for me. There are a number of warning, so I can't work out which is the specific one that's causing problems.

```
C:\Users\Phucker>npm install -g express
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/connect/2.8.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/commander/1.2.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser/0.0.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/0.3.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie/0.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/buffer-crc32/0.2.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/0.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/methods/0.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/send/0.1.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-signature/1.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/debug
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie/0.1.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/commander/1.2.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser/0.0.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/connect/2.8.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/buffer-crc32/0.2.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/0.1.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/methods/0.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/send/0.1.3
npm WARN package.json methods@0.0.1 No README.md file found!
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-signature/1.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/debug
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/0.3.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/keypress
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/qs/0.6.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bytes/0.2.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pause/0.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uid2/0.0.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable/1.0.14
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/keypress
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/uid2/0.0.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable/1.0.14
npm WARN package.json uid2@0.0.2 No README.md file found!
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/pause/0.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bytes/0.2.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/qs/0.6.5
C:\Users\Phucker\AppData\Roaming\npm\express -> C:\Users\Phucker\AppData\Ro
\node_modules\express\bin\express
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Phucker\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
o requires express@'3.0.x' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Phucker\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
s,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 3.3.4
express@3.3.4 C:\Users\Phucker\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\express
├── methods@0.0.1
├── fresh@0.1.0
├── range-parser@0.0.4
├── cookie-signature@1.0.1
├── buffer-crc32@0.2.1
├── cookie@0.1.0
├── debug@0.7.2
├── mkdirp@0.3.5
├── commander@1.2.0 (keypress@0.1.0)
├── send@0.1.3 (mime@1.2.9)
└── connect@2.8.4 (uid2@0.0.2, pause@0.0.1, qs@0.6.5, bytes@0.2.0, form
0.14)

C:\Users\Phucker>express -c stylus express_example

   create : express_example
   create : express_example/package.json
   create : express_example/app.js
   create : express_example/public
   create : express_example/public/javascripts
   create : express_example/public/images
   create : express_example/public/stylesheets
   create : express_example/public/stylesheets/style.styl
   create : express_example/routes
   create : express_example/routes/index.js
   create : express_example/routes/user.js
   create : express_example/views
   create : express_example/views/layout.jade
   create : express_example/views/index.jade

   install dependencies:
     $ cd express_example && npm install

   run the app:
     $ node app


C:\Users\Phucker>cd express_example && npm install
npm WARN package.json application-name@0.0.1 No README.md file found!
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express/3.3.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/stylus
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jade
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/express/3.3.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express/-/express-3.3.4.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/express/-/express-3.3.4.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/stylus
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/stylus/-/stylus-0.34.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/stylus/-/stylus-0.34.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/jade
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jade/-/jade-0.33.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/jade/-/jade-0.33.0.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/connect/2.8.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/commander/1.2.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser/0.0.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/0.3.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie/0.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/buffer-crc32/0.2.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/0.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/methods/0.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/send/0.1.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-signature/1.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/debug
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/transformers/2.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/monocle/0.1.48
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/character-parser/1.0.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/with
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/constantinople
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cssom
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/connect/2.8.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser/0.0.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/commander/1.2.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/0.3.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie/0.1.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/buffer-crc32/0.2.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/0.1.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/methods/0.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/send/0.1.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-signature/1.0.1
npm WARN package.json methods@0.0.1 No README.md file found!
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/debug
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/keypress
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bytes/0.2.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uid2/0.0.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pause/0.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/qs/0.6.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable/1.0.14
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/monocle/0.1.48
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/monocle/-/monocle-0.1.48.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/with
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cssom
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cssom/-/cssom-0.2.5.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/keypress
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bytes/0.2.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/uid2/0.0.2
npm WARN package.json uid2@0.0.2 No README.md file found!
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/pause/0.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/qs/0.6.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable/1.0.14
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/monocle/-/monocle-0.1.48.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/transformers/2.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/transformers/-/transformers-2.0
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cssom/-/cssom-0.2.5.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/constantinople
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/transformers/-/transformers-2.0
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/character-parser/1.0.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/character-parser/-/character-pa
2.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/character-parser/-/character-pa
2.tgz
npm ERR! addPlacedTarball Could not remove "C:\\Users\\Phucker\\AppData\\
npm-cache\\character-parser\\1.0.2\\package"
npm ERR! Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir 'C:\Users\Phucker\AppData\Roaming\npm-ca
cter-parser\1.0.2\package'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program F
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\Phucker\express_example
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.0
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.14
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Phucker\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\character-parser
ckage
npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
npm ERR! errno 53
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Phucker\express_example\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0

C:\Users\Phucker\express_example>
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the specific directory works for me. It will be

```
C:\\Users\\Phucker\\AppData\\
npm-cache\\character-parser\\1.0.2\\package
```

in your case. ( I used node.js for cordova installation).

Thanks,
prodeveloper